# How to use Customize syntax highlighting on Mobaxterm

Tags: mobaxterm

in the Mobaxterm Configuration, I clicked on Customize in the Terminal -> Syntax highlighting section.
Then, i clicked on "Use regular expressions (experts only)" and added the following regex for "Cyan":

```
\[.* CEST\]
```

I expected this to make my timestamps in my log files in Cyan.
The timestamps are in this format:

```
[10/16/20 16:21:35:457 CEST]
```

However nothing happens. Can you help me to understand this feature?

Thank you

Comment: How do you view your log files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a full regex, I based it off their built in reg

```
    [^A-Za-z_&-]\[[0-9][0-9]?\/[0-9][0-9]?\/[0-9][0-9]? [0-9][0-9]?\:[0-9][0-9]?\:[0-9][0-9]?\:[0-9][0-9]?[0-9]? CEST\][^A-Za-z_&-]
```

I know its 4 month old question but if you need it, this might be helpful.